# how to redirect to "page not found"

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, codebehind

how to redirect to "page not found" for code in SharePoint 2013?

To page /page/PageNotFoundError.aspx

Does anyone knows how can I do that?

example:

```
item.status = rejected
then this.page.redirect = pagenofound.aspx
```

**the page exists, I just need to go to it, for code, following given conditions**

Comment: which sharepoint version you are asking?

Comment: in SharePoint 2013 :)

Comment: check this one http://sharepoint-community.net/profiles/blogs/how-to-create-custom-error-pages-on-sharepoint-2013

Comment: Did you mean re-direct?
If so, perhaps this might [help](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/sharepoint-2010-page-not-found-404/) you. I'm sorry if I have misunderstood your question!

Comment: thank you,the page exists, I just need to go to it, for code, following given conditions

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can update the default 404 page for the webapp using powershell

```
$webapp =Get-SPWebApplication http://<SiteUrl> 
$webapp.FileNotFoundPage = "custom404.html" 
$webapp.update()
```

Source:
http://www.spdeveloper.co.in/articles/pages/custom-page-not-found-page-sharepoint-2010.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something as [this](http://blog.mastykarz.nl/sharepoint-2010-page-not-found-404/)

Anyone have a link showing how to do this in shp2013?